# Can I have my Wordpress blog's subdomain hosted on Blogger.com?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, subdomain, godaddy, blogger

I want my wordpress blog's subdomain to be hosted on Blogger.

My current host is bluehost and I bought domain from Godaddy. Will it work?

Why would I like to do this?
Because I having something that will work better on Blogger. And I just don't want to buy a new domain for it.

Please present your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. All you need to do is create a CNAME record for the subdomain and point it to blogger. Your main domain can still be pointed to Bluehost.

Comment: I can't edit DNS zone files. It says - hosted by different registerer.

Comment: @Abhishek if you pointed the nameservers to BlueHost you will need to setup the CNAME record there.